# Can I create a pytest.fixture that returns combinations of arguments?

Tags: python, pytest

The inputs to the the algorithm being tested is a list of strings (known in advance) with associated years, e.g. all of the following are valid inputs:

```
['A_2018', 'B_2019', 'C_2018']
[]
['A_2018']
```

I've got the following simple year fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=range(2018, 2025))
def year(request):
    return request.param
```

If I create individual fixtures for each valid string:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['A', ''])
def A(request, year):
    return request.param, year

@pytest.fixture(params=['B', ''])
def B(request, year):
    return request.param, year
```

etc. and use them in tests like:

```
def test_foo(A, B):
    args = []
    if A[0]:
        args.append('%s_%d' % A)
    if B[0]:
        args.append('%s_%d' % B)
    assert old_algorithm(args) == new_algorithm(args)
```

I get

```
['A_2018', 'B_2018']
['A_2019', 'B_2019']
['A_2020', 'B_2020']
```

etc. where the year is always the same for both parameters.

Is there a way to create all combinations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is a fixture generating combinations a requirement? Because otherwise, applying `pytest.mark.parametrize` separately for each test input arg generates the input args combinations just fine. In the example below both fixtures `A` and `B` are parametrized separately, generating `(2025 - 2018)**2` tests in total:

```
@pytest.fixture
def A(request):
    return 'A', request.param


@pytest.fixture
def B(request):
    return 'B', request.param


@pytest.mark.parametrize('A', range(2018, 2025), indirect=True, ids=lambda year: 'A({})'.format(year))
@pytest.mark.parametrize('B', range(2018, 2025), indirect=True, ids=lambda year: 'B({})'.format(year))
def test_foo(A, B):
    assert A[0] == 'A' and B[0] == 'B'
```

As a result, 49 tests are produced:

```
$ pytest --collect-only | grep collected
collected 49 items
```

Comment: Great to see that it's possible, although I'm not sure I understand why/how A is `("A", 2018)` etc. when `indirect=True` and just `2018` if it's false..?  It's also a bit wordy, which was the impetus for parametrizing the fixture, but I guess I can use the recipe from (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources) to make it easier to use, now that I know about `indirect=True` :-)

Comment: The `indirect` flag determines whether the parameter is passed directly (`indirect=False`, then `A` is a parameter with value as is and the fixture `A` is not used), or indirectly (`indirect=True`, the parameter is passed to fixture `A` as argument first and the result of the fixture is passed to test). The means of using it was just to construct an example that has roughly the same beahviour as yours.

Comment: As for generating tests with `metafunc`, yes, it's the ultimate parametrizing hook where you can tune and alter almost everything, but can grow large pretty fast if you need different behaviours for different test types.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation, that actually helped a lot.  As for pytest_generate_tests/metafunc growing too big.. I thought the solution was lots of small directories..?

Comment: Very nice solution! I have a follow up question. How can we add one more test case on top of these 49 cases? Lets say we want to add the case of (2030, 2030) and make 50 items in total to run `test_foo(A, B)`; the main goal is to reuse the `test_foo` in the case of the new case.